# How do I easily sum up values in different columns?

Tags: r, sum, multiple-columns

I have a very large data set where I would like to combine columns that belong to the same group. After searching here on StackOverflow and the rest of the internet I can't seem to find something that is working for me since I have thousands of columns.

I have a data set in which I can analyse data on 6 different levels. On the highest level there are only three different column names, but the lower the level, the more different column names there are. I want to add up the values in the different columns. I am unsure how to start with this. I have tried 
`gather()`, `colSums()`, `unite()`, and `sum()` but I don't seem to be getting what I want.

To make it more clear, here is an example of the data that I have:

```
K   A   A   B   B   B   C   C   C
P   a   b   c   c   d   e   e   f
C   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
---------------------------------
1   0   4   5   4   6   6   9   8
2   2   5   4   7   5   6   3   2
3   0   3   0   1   2   4   5   4
4   4   6   0   0   4   1   3   1
5   7   5   0   0   3   1   2   2
6   1   2   0   0   2   2   3   1
```

Depending on which level I want to analyse (K, P or C) I have to combine different columns. On every row, an individual observation is shown. For example, I want to analyse this on the 'p' level I would like to get a result like this:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f
--------------------------
1   0   4   9   6   15  8
2   2   5   11  5   9   2
3   0   3   1   2   9   4
4   4   6   0   4   4   1
5   7   5   0   3   3   2
6   1   2   0   2   5   1
```

Is there a way to do this? I can either do it with column names or with position (preferably with positions as the column names are very long).

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: I would to a wide to long transform, then do aggregations using whatever groups you need. Let's see that `gather` code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data:

```
df=read.table(text = "
K   A   A   B   B   B   C   C   C
P   a   b   c   c   d   e   e   f
C   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   0   4   5   4   6   6   9   8
2   2   5   4   7   5   6   3   2
3   0   3   0   1   2   4   5   4
4   4   6   0   0   4   1   3   1
5   7   5   0   0   3   1   2   2
6   1   2   0   0   2   2   3   1",header=F,row.names =1,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

transpose data

```
d=data.frame(t(df),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

convert factors to numeric data

```
d[,-1:-3]=sapply(d[,-1:-3], as.numeric)
```

aggregate data based on the selected groups

```
res=aggregate.data.frame(x = d[,-1:-3],by = list(d$P),FUN = sum)

    > res
  Group.1 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1       a  0  2  0  4  7  1
2       b  4  5  3  6  5  2
3       c  9 11  1  0  0  0
4       d  6  5  2  4  3  2
5       e 15  9  9  4  3  5
6       f  8  2  4  1  2  1
```

for other groups:

```
res=aggregate.data.frame(x = d[,-1:-3],by = list(d$K),FUN = sum)
res=aggregate.data.frame(x = d[,-1:-3],by = list(d$C),FUN = sum)
```

finally you could transpose the `res` again.

```
row.names(res)=res$Group.1  
res=res[,-1]
res=t(res)
> res
   a b  c d  e f
X1 0 4  9 6 15 8
X2 2 5 11 5  9 2
X3 0 3  1 2  9 4
X4 4 6  0 4  4 1
X5 7 5  0 3  3 2
X6 1 2  0 2  5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0,2,0,4,7,1), 
               col2 = c(4,5,3,6,5,2), 
               col3 = c(5,4,0,0,0,0),
               col4 = c(4,7,1,0,0,0),
               col5 = c(6,5,2,4,3,2),
               col6 = c(6,6,4,1,1,2),
               col7 = c(9,3,5,3,2,3),
               col8 = c(8,2,4,1,2,1))

level_example = as.factor(c("a","b","c","c","d","e","e","f"))

group_columnsby_level <- function(level){
  transposed_df <- data.table::transpose(df)
  transposed_df["level"] <- level
  df_result <- transposed_df %>% group_by(level) %>% summarise_all(sum)
  df_result <- data.table::transpose(df_result)
  colnames(df_result) <- df_result[1,]
  df_result <- df_result[-1,]
  return(df_result)
}

group_columnsby_level(level_example)
```

Comment: This works well for a small number of columns, but for >5000 columns this unfortunately is too difficult.

Answer (score -2):

It's always better to include the data.

You can achieve what you want with `dplyr`, install it you do not have it already.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

Then use `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(s = rowSums(.))
```

Comment: This completely ignores OP's weirdly confusing data structure. I don't see how it relates to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this but it does not work with the data set that I have